# Python build-in exceptions - how to get exception fields

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

I have the following error message:

```
type object 'SomeClass' has no attribute 'some_class_field'
```

The exception is of type 'AtrributeError'.

Is there any way to change the error message to:

```
Provider class 'SomeClass' has no field 'some_class_field'
```

I guess those parameters are saved in the python exception class and I think there could be a solution of the following type:

```
try:
    # some code
except AtrributeError as ae:
    print("Provider class '{0}' has no field '{1}'").format(ae.type_object, ae.attribute))
    exit(1)
```

Comment: you can always extract the values from the exception object. Why do you need to customize the message like this, though?

Comment: @Jim Fasarakis Hilliard I was wondering if it could happen whithout defining my own exceptions, that is why I asked. Also I thought it would be better more understandable for people that don't write in python.

Comment: Don't define your own exceptions; get the exception message from `ae.args[0]` and extract the parts you need. Then print them out (using `.format` or whatever else you need).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply You cant do that.

if you do like that again you will exception like this

```
    print("Provider class '{0}' has no field '{1}'").format(ae.type_object, ae.attribute)
AttributeError: 'exceptions.AttributeError' object has no attribute 'type_object'
```

from Jim Fasarakis Hilliard comment:

> we can't access like that because ae has only message key. it doesn't
>   have any other key for what you are trying to access.  Don't define
>   your own exceptions; get the exception message from ae.args[0] and
>   extract the parts you need. Then print them out (using .format or
>   whatever else you need). – Jim Fasarakis Hilliard

Comment: Please add the idea of the  Jim Fasarakis Hilliard comments as a short explanatory text and I will accept your answer. This is for more comprehensive closure of the topic, thank you in advance.

Comment: @stefan.stt thank you. i  update my answer. please check